# Java: Convert direct ByteBuffer to double[]

Tags: java

What is the best way to do that?

I tried the following:

```
ByteBuffer cacheBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(nm(nLimit,0));  //where nm(nLimit,0) is a large number
double[] cache=cacheBuffer.asDoubleBuffer().array();
```

But I got this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.nio.DoubleBuffer.array(Unknown Source)
```

Why?

Edit:

It looks like the javadoc "Returns the double array that backs this buffer  (optional operation)." actually means array() method is simply returning the double array that is already backing this buffer. I thought it is going to convert the buffer to double[] somehow. So now it makes sense I got an exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will only work if you expect your array to merely be a *copy*.

```
final DoubleBuffer buffer = cacheBuffer.asDoubleBuffer();
final double[] copy = new double[buffer.remaining()];
buffer.get(copy);
```

The reason your attempt fails is because `array` is only supported for *non-direct* buffers; direct buffers are not backed by an array.

Comment: Is there anyway to make buffer and copy pointing to the same area of memory?

Comment: Just read your edit. So there is no way to make it work unless I change all double[] to some DoubleBuffer access method in my entire project.

Comment: No way to point Java anywhere since Java has no such concept of memory.

Answer (score 1):

array() is an optional operation of Buffers. Buffer implementations may/ may not support this operation. Invoke hasArray() to check if the operation is supported and then proceed accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

if you want a shallow copy, use clone()